# HERE Route Matching v8 - how to define stopover waypoints when using a trace file?

Tags: here-api, heremaps, here-olp

I use the Here Rout Matching v8 API to match routes from sequences of GPS coordinates. I pass the GPS coordinates as a CSV trace file in the POST request body (as documented here https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-matching/api-reference.html). The resulting route contains one leg, which in turn contains the sequence of links connecting the leg's origin to the leg's destination.

In my use case, some of the GPS coordinates in the trace file are stop locations. Can I change my request so that the matched route is divided into multiple legs?
To be clear, I would like

- first leg from the origin to the first stop
- second leg from the first stop to the second stop
- ...
- last leg from the last stop to the destination

I tried passing additional columns in the CSV trace file (speed and time, indicating that the GPS trace actually stops at the stopover locations) but I still got a matched route with a single leg.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's limitation to the number of waypoints you can use. If you want to use more waypoints it's recommended to use the import route functionality. Also, there are more configurations like offroad driving etc are on the way for importRoute, you can check once with the Sales Executive from HERE. I have found this product may be it will help you - https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/api-reference.html . It's always better to explain your exact use case, input and expected output. It helps other people to suggest you solutions.